# How to wait for 'message' event inside the 'install' event in service worker?

Tags: service-worker

I have a scenario where i need to send postMessage of latest version files array  from client to service worker on the update event of service worker.

current code

```
reg.onupdatefound = function() {
        // The updatefound event implies that reg.installing is set; see
        // https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-registration-updatefound-event
        var installingWorker = reg.installing;

        console.log('on update found');

        // service worker is updated with version name eesh   
        if(reg.installing)
        {
          reg.installing.postMessage({
          data: cacheUrls()
          });
        }


        installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
          switch (installingWorker.state) {
            case 'installed':
              if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will
                // have been added to the cache.
                // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
                // message in the page's interface.
                console.log('New or updated content is available. yo yo');
                // navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({data: location})  
              } else {
                // At this point, everything has been precached.
                // It's the perfect time to display a "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', reg.scope);

              }
              break;

            case 'redundant':
              console.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
              break;
          }
        };
      };
};
```

But sometimes the installation happens first and then "message" event is listened in service worker. How do i wait for 'message' event inside 'install' event of service worker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
// sw.js

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    const installPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do install stuff, like caching resources, etc.

        self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            // 1. do something with the received data
            // 2. remove this event listener
            resolve();
        });
    });

    e.waitUntil(installPromise);
});
```

`e.waitUntil()` accepts a `Promise` so we give it one. The `install` phase gets completed only when the promise passed to `e.waitUntil()` resolves. We only resolve that `Promise` once we've already received the message from the client.